# Is there any purpose to collecting duplicate weapons in System Shock (2023)?

Tags: system-shock-2023

In the remastered version of *System Shock* (2023), you can find duplicates of multiple weapons early on in the game.

There seems to be no way to scrap or recycle these weapons, or to trade them in at any of the stations. There also doesn't seem to be any way to upgrade them on different paths (Upgrading one to be a sniper rifle, and another to be an assault rifle).

Other than salvaging ammunition from them, is there any reason to pick up a duplicate of any functioning weapons?